# Python - error with OOP

Tags: python

[image: I have got stuck with Python classes . Please help.]

I am getting an error stating that global name 'data' not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference `data` variable using the `self` variable.

Like -

```
with open(self.data,'r') as f:
```

Comment: Also , I would advice you to accept answers (for all your questions) (by clicking the tick mark on the left side of the answer) , would really help the community.

Answer (score 5):

You want to do

```
def read_data(self):
    with open(self.data, 'r') as f
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference with `self.data`

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct this line :

`with open(data, 'r') as f:`

To :

`with open(self.data, 'r') as f:`

Answer (score 0):

In `ParseCSV` class constructor you set `self.data` by `data` parameter, this means that you can access `data` by `self` in other methods of the class, change line 6 to below form:

```
...
    with open(self.data, 'r') as f:
...
```